# Geth error: fatal: could not list accounts: index 0 higher than number of accounts 0

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
geth --datadir mychaindata --nodiscover --unlock 0 --mine 1
```

and getting the above error.

When I enter `geth account list`, I see two accounts.

What gives?

Comment: What the output of `geth --datadir mychaindata account list`?

Comment: WARN [01-31|15:57:35] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default

Answer (score 1):

The option `--datadir` declare where are your data would be placed, the whole data includes keystores, database and so on. When you're invoking the command `geth account list` it's uses the default datadir (`~/.ethereum`). Looks like that directory doesn't contains any accounts. In order to force address you can use the `--etherbase` option:

```
geth --datadir mychaindata --nodiscover --unlock 0 --mine --etherbase YOUR_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE
```

<sub>[Command-Line-Options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options)</sub>

Comment: Where do I get the address to pass to the --etherbase option?

Comment: You can generate new `geth ---datadir mychaindata account new` one.

Comment: What's the command to list existing addresses?

Comment: There is a good documentation and wiki check it https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options